# How to select from dynamically added elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to let users to select from rooms which are appended into dom  dynamically when the user's login is successfull:

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var username = $('#login-username').val()
    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    socket.emit('loginUser', {
        username: $('#login-username').val() ,
        password: $('#login-password').val() 

    }, function(rooms) {
        $('.login-area').addClass("hidden");
        console.log('rooms are: ', rooms); // ['Public','Fun','Cars']
        $('.choose-room').removeClass("hidden");
        $.each(rooms, function( index, room ) {
            var li= $('<li></li>');
            li.html('<h4 class="room-selector" id=' + room + '>'+ room  + '</h4>');

          $('#roomlist').append(li);
        });
        $('.error-area').addClass("hidden");


    });
});


$('.room-selector').on('click',  function(){
    console.log('im clicked');
    var roomName = this.attr("id");
    console.log('selected room is:', roomName);
});
```

The html div into which the room list is rendered:

```
<div class="choose-room hidden">
   <ul class="list-unstyled" id="roomlist">

    </ul>
 </div>
```

But the `.room-selector` does not show anything in the console when a room is clicked.

I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: `$('#roomlist').on('click', '.room-selector',  function(){
    ......
});`

Comment: @Satpal this catches the click, but now I get `TypeError: this.attr is not a function`. How to fix this in order to get the element's id?

Comment: Use `this.id` to access property or use ` $(this).attr("id");`

Answer (score 0):

this should work, take a try

```
 $('#roomlist li').on('click','.room-selector',  function(){
        console.log('im clicked');
        var roomName = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log('selected room is:', roomName);
    });
```

Comment: No, does not work.

Comment: change this to $(this) and check

Comment: Right, but the first line should be `$('#roomlist').on('click','.room-selector',  function(){` as @Satpal indicated above.

Comment: both are correct, i am specifying a accurate mark up ul -> li -> item; while satpal said ul -> item

Comment: Well for some reason `$('#roomlist li').on...` not work for me but `$('#roomlist').on...` does.

Comment: @narad `$('#roomlist li')` didn't worked as `li` is also dynamically created  so you can use `$('#roomlist').on('click','li .room-selector', function(){`